# Generate barcode image from PIL.EPSImageFile instance

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, eps

I want to generate a barcode image. So, I used elaphe package. It works correctly but it returns PIL.EPSImageFile instance. I don't know how I can convert it to image format like SVG, PNG or JPG.

The code I have written is:

```
barcode('code128', 'barcodetest')
```

And it returns:

`<PIL.EpsImagePlugin.EpsImageFile image mode=RGB size=145x72 at 0x9AA47AC>`

How can I convert this instance to image?
Actually I think my question is wrong but I don't know how to explain it well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply save that file object to something with a `.png` or `.jpg` filename:

```
bc = barcode('qrcode',
    'Hello Barcode Writer In Pure PostScript.',
    options=dict(version=9, eclevel='M'), 
    margin=10, data_mode='8bits')
bc.save('yourfile.jpg')
```

or state the format explicitly:

```
bc.save('yourfile.jpg', 'JPEG')
```

PIL will then convert the image to the correct format.

Note that the PIL EPS module uses the `gs` command from the [Ghostscript project](http://www.ghostscript.com/) to do it's conversions, you'll need to have it installed for this to work.

Comment: The `EPS` module uses the `gs` command to convert between formats; install the [`ghostscript` package](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/) for your architecture.

Comment: Ah, I think the generated barcode is actually empty. There is no data to convert.

Comment: @VahidJavaherifar: I am not familiar with the API of the `elaphe` library itself, but the updated answer works for conversions to PNG or JPEG. You'll now have to figure out how to generate a *proper* barcode with that API, but conversion is not the issue here.